# (linux) Sendmail se puede especificar en la línea de comandos un servidor smtp distinto al de la configuración?

Tags: linux, email, línea-de-comandos

Querría saber si con el comando de "sendmail" se puede especificar en la línea de comandos **otro smtp** que **no** sea el que tenga definido en sus ficheros de configuración.

Me lo pregunto porque a través de mailx sé que se puede realizar, pero con este comando no consigo enviar un correo formateado en html que luego se vea correctamente en el cliente de correo (es decir, que se recibe el correo con las etiquetas de html).

He mirado en numerosas páginas y todos dan la misma solución, la cual no me funciona.

Estoy usando los comandos en Redhat.

Información de sendmail en el sistema operativo que estoy utilizando:
- Versión `sendmail-8.14.7-4.el7.x86_64`
- Cabecera del manual de sendmail (después de comprobarlo por segunda vez): `SENDMAIL(8) System Manager's Manual`. Creo que no viene proporcionado por potfix sino que es del propio sendmail, aparece la propia página `http://sendmail.org`

El error al que me refiero al enviar un email formateado en HTML con mailx es que llega el correo sin formatear, es decir, incluyendo los tags html. Lo he probado con:

-`$BODY_HTML |mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "Subject" S smtp=smtp://xxxx to@address`
-`$BODY_HTML" | mailx -v -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" -S smtp=smtp://xxxx -S from="$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS($FRIENDLY_NAME)" "$TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS" "$TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS2`

La versión de mailx es `mailx-12.5.12.el7_0.x89_64` y en su manual dice: `Heirloom mailx 12.5  10/9/10`.

Aportar que estoy utilizando ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7 como servidor de correo.

Gracias de antemano,
Un saludo

Comment: ¿Cual es la misma solución que te dan y no te funciona? por qué no te funciona, algun error ?

Comment: El comando sendmail es tomado muchas veces por el paquete del servidor smtp que utilices en tu sistema, por lo que puede que los comandos y parámetros sean diferentes de la solución que dices haber encontrado. Haz un man sendmail y dinos que te pone en la cabecera. En mi caso el sendmail es proporcionado por postfix y en el man aparece esto `NAME      sendmail - Postfix to Sendmail compatibility interface`. Indica también lo que estás intentando probar como bien dice lois6b.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por vuestras respuestas. con respecto a la cabecera del man de sendmail pone "MAILQ(1) General Commands manual" (el sistema operativo es redhat)  con respecto a la solución que no me funciona para enviar correos formateados en html con mailx es "mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s "Subject" to@address <test.html" y esta "echo -e "$BODY" | mailx -v -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" -S smtp=smtp://xxxx -S from="$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS($FRIENDLY_NAME)" "$TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS" "$TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS2"". Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor,  [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/86949/edit) la pregunta para añadir la ifnormacion, no en los comentarios.

Comment: En debian el comando mailx que tengo yo no soporta el parámetro -S. Que error te da cuando intentas enviar el mailx ? Por otra parte mira a ver si tienes disponible para tu redhat el comando sendemail (ojo que no es el sendmail de siempre, tiene una e más).